# Filtering Google Map markers through javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, filter

I'm currently trying to create filters that can make markers on Google maps filter in & out. The lat/lng are all stored in a database. I'm then parsing it to an XML document so that Google maps can interpret everything stored in my database and plot them onto the map. This works perfectly.

However i now wanna create filters which will enable to filter me markers from the map, something as simple as just the name.

The code reading the XML document is below:

```
downloadUrl('php2xml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
```

The code plotting the marker onto the map is simply:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point
              });
```

I've tried the following but just can't get it to work! :

```
filterMarkers = function (name) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (marker.name == name || name.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console at all ?

Comment: I'm getting no errors at all, i've just noticed it is removing a marker, but not in the way i want it too.

So for example, if the name matches "test" i want every marker other than the marker associated with "test" to disappear, however at the moment its doing it the other way around, and i've tried swapping the marker.setVisible(true), marker.setVisible(false) around!


-EDIT | it's not removing the marker based on the condition though, it's just removing the last loaded marker ?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment suggest you're calling `downloadUrl` multiple times so you keep adding markers but don't remove the ones that are there.

The array `markers` is probably set with the last result of `downloadUrl` so all previous results are not there anymore thus you can't mutate them to hide them.

Not sure what it is you want but probably should either remove all markers before you use the result of `downloadUrl` to add markers or use `concat` of Array.prototype to add additional results of `downloadUrl`.

```
markers = markers.concat([newMarkersFromDownload]);
//only add newMarkersfromDownload to map because the other ones were already there
```